# How to get admin details like first name, last name,email using Rest API in Magento 2

Tags: api, rest-api

How to get admin details like first name, last name,email  using Rest API in Magento 2. Any options to add custom attribute like GST No, company name, contact number, Bank details

Comment: Are you talking about admin user or general Customer

Comment: Yes I talk about Admin user

Comment: Admin user does not have any field like  `GST No, company name, contact number, Bank details`

Comment: Any options to create it